# VBA: declare memory space or array in struct passed to DLL?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a struct that I pass by reference from Excel to an OS library. In VBA I need to declare and allocate the memory, before I pass the reference to the OS library.
I could, of course, just allocate some new memory, and manipulate the memory in VBA using pointers. But I'd prefer to use VBA declarations in VBA, so that I can use VBA statements to read and set values.
The problem is that the struct contains a byte array of size NCCS. I can't use a VBA array, because that allocates a SAFEARRAY structure.

Is there any way other than just naming and declaring a lot of dummy variables? Is there any way to use an Array? Is there any way to declare a VBA array that points to the Dummy variable region?

```
Type termios
    c_iflag As Long 
    c_oflag As Long
    c_cflag As Long
    c_lflag As Long
    'c_cc(0 To NCCS - 1) As Byte
    c0 as byte: c1 as byte: c2 as byte: c3 as byte: c4 as byte
    c5 as byte: c6 as byte: c7 as byte: c8 as byte: c9 as byte
    c10 as byte: c11 as byte: c12 as byte: c13 as byte: c14 as byte
    c15 as byte: c16 as byte: c17 as byte: c18 as byte: c19 as byte
    c_ispeed As Long
    c_ospeed As Long
End Type
```

Comment: You could use a class, similar to your type, and have a property for `NCCS`, then this `redims` said array.

Comment: You can use `c_cc as String * 20` to define a memory zone of 20 adjacent bytes

Comment: Since it's a numeric array, you should be able to pass the first item by reference. I must admit I'm not sure if that will work within a UDT.